# JavaScript Removing Elements Dynamically! removeChild

Tags: javascript, forms, button, materialize, removechild

Technology I am using is materialize and vanilla js. I've created a materialize button that opens a model. within the model is a form that takes user input, then places the input text onto the main page, when the Submit button is triggered. then I have a button that should remove/delete the input posted. So the issue I'm having is that the JavaScript linked to the button which should delete/removeChild isn't working. please help :)

```js
// ----------------Models Materialize Framework----------------
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
  });




//Delete From The Dom
const delExerciseBtn = document.querySelector('.del-exercise-btn');

delExerciseBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
if(e.target.className == 'delete'){
  const h6 = e.target.parentElement;
  delExerciseBtn.removeChild(h6);
}

});

// Add User's To the Dom.
const addExerciseDom = document.querySelector('.exercise-dom');
const exerciseForm = document.querySelector('.exercises-form');
const disabledExersiceBtn = document.querySelector('.disabled-exersicebtn');


exerciseForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

  // Get Input Value
  const value = exerciseForm.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;

  // Create Elements
  const h6 = document.createElement('h6');
  
  // Add Content
  h6.textContent = value;
  
  // Append To Dom
  addExerciseDom.appendChild(h6);  

  //Disable Btn
  disabledExersiceBtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');


});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   
      <title></title>

      <!-- Google icons -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  
      <!-- Sytle.css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      
    
</head>
<body>
   
<!----- user's input ------->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 center valign-wrapper center-align">
   <div class=" exercise-dom delete"> <!--Users text input h6----> </div>
   </div>
</div>


<!-- Btn/Modals/form -->
   <div class="row">
   <!-- Dom Btn -->
    <div class="col s12 center ">
      <a href="#exercise" class="btn-floating btn-small darken-4 z-depth-2 black center modal-trigger disabled-exersicebtn">
        <i class="material-icons white-text">add </i>
      </a>
    </div>
    
   <!-- Modal/form -->
  <div class="modal modal-position" id="exercise">
   <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="row exercises-padding">
     <form class="col s12 exercises-form" autocomplete="off">
       <div class="input-field col s10"> 
         <i class="material-icons prefix">fitness_center</i>
          <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input"  class="autocomplete center">
            <label for="autocomplete-input" ><h6>Exercises</h6></label>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <input class="modal-close btn black" type="submit" value="Submit">
       </div>
     </form>
    </div>     
   </div>
  </div>
  
  
<!-- Remove Users Btn -->
  <div class="col s12 center remove-padding">
    <a href="#" class="btn-floating btn-small darken-4 z-depth-2 black center modal-trigger del-exercise-btn">
      <i class="material-icons white-text ">remove </i>
    </a>
  </div>
  
  
     <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
       
     <!-- app.JavaScript -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no ".del-exercise-btn'" class element in your HTML and that may only be the first error in the row. you need an element with the class or id you are referring too in order to be able to manipulate it via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

- you have a nesting error in your HTML, a `</div>` is missing, which is why the DOM doesn't contain the form

  1. check the DOM with developer tools by inspecting elements, and you'll see that the structure is wrong
  2. you can also use for example Codepen's "Analyze HTML" function in the HTML pane to check your HTML
- the `<form>`'s class is `Exercises-form`, and the selector `.exercises-form` (from `const exerciseForm = document.querySelector('.exercises-form');`) therefore can't find the element, as CSS class names are case-sensitive. `exerciseForm` then becomes `null`, which causes the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`
- the delete button still doesn't work. I suggest to you try for yourself. Use the browser developer tools, especially the DOM element inspector and the console for interactive tests for your selector queries (and the element you select in the element inspector is accessible as `$0` in the console.). There are many tutorials a Google search away.

Additional note: I oversaw that there's already an `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {...` at the top of the file. You can put your code there, no need for another `DOMContentLoaded` event listener (although it doesn't hurt either).

---

Original answer:

You get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

that means that

```
const delExerciseBtn = document.querySelector('.del-exercise-btn');
```

couldn't find the node and returned `null`.

Probable reason: code runs too early, browser has not yet constructed the DOM.

Solution: wrap your code in a [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) handler:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const delExerciseBtn = document.querySelector('.del-exercise-btn');
    // ...
});
```

Comment: If you setup a showcase on another platform, e.g. Stackblitz, CodeSandbox, Codepen, ... it would be easier to see whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
const h6 = e.target.parentElement;
delExerciseBtn.removeChild(h6);
```

You are trying to remove its parent from a button. And you need to remove the button from the parent.

```
const h6 = e.target.parentElement;
h6.removeChild(e.target);
```